# Angular2 routing canActivate and AuthGuard (JWT) with user role parameter

Tags: javascript, authentication, angular, roles, angular2-routing

In this [exaple project](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/app.routes.ts) with JWT authentication we se how to allow only authenticated users to some route:

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import { Home } from './home';
import { Login } from './login';
import { Signup } from './signup';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/auth.guard';

export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '',       component:  Login },
  { path: 'login',  component: Login },
  { path: 'signup', component: Signup },
  { path: 'home',   component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: '**',     component: Login },
];
```

I would like make step further and also indicate what user role have 'access' to route - but I don't know how to pass argument to canActivate [AuthGuard (src)](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/common/auth.guard.ts). So I would like to achieve something like this (for instance I have two roles: Admin and Employee):

```
  { path: 'home',   component: Home, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'users',   component: AdminUsers, canActivate: [AuthGuard('Admin')] },
  { path: 'users',   component: Employees, canActivate: [AuthGuard('Employee')] },
```

Where my AuthGuard could look something like this (where userRole(= Admin or Employee or null) is passed parameter to AuthGuard):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(userRole) {
    if (!userRole || JWT.user().role == userRole) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

where JWT.user.role is helper which read user role stored in JWT token. Is there a way to do something similar like above idea?

Comment: We can't you extend AuthGuard as AdminAuthGuard and UserAuthGuard and pass these in canActivate hook in rote declaration

Comment: I konw, this way - it is workaround. But I would like to know, do exists other way similar to above question idea.

Comment: I don't think so as during route declaration you are specifing only guard class. You can pass multiple class though.

Comment: I am a newbie to Angular5 and I am struggling with the same problem. if your problem got solved then can you please share your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature for `CanActivate` won't allow you to pass a `userRole` like you want to. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.4/modules/%40angular/router/src/interfaces.ts#L54

It's probably best to do separate classes for each of your user role cases. That's the guidance in the official docs too: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html

Comment: this answer was correct, in the time when I ask question  - this is reason why green 'check' is here. But for new angular version there is better solution (read answers below)

Answer (score 85):

You can set the `data` parameter of the route with the role like this

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ 
  path: 'account/super-secure', 
  component: SuperSecureComponent, 
  canActivate: [RoleGuard], 
  data: { roles: ['super-admin', 'admin'] } 
}];
```

and then have this in `canActivate` of `RoleGuard`:

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    let roles = route.data["roles"] as Array<string>;
    return (roles == null || roles.indexOf("the-logged-user-role") != -1);
}
```

I think this could be another way of doing it instead of creating guard for every role. I would actually take this rout since it requires less code and handles the problem very nicely.

Comment: When I try use you solution i see following error:
`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.` 
I think your solution works only for old versions of angular2

Comment: @Kamil Kietczewski, the solution works with angular 2 (~2.0.1) at least and with the new router ~3.0.1. It might be that you are using the old router.

Comment: I tested it for Angular 2.0.0-rc.3 - this version I use in my project - but I will try to upgrade my project and test your solution... so be patient

Comment: if your users can have multiple roles, you can edit this to figure out the intersection of the route.roles array and user.roles array: `user.roles.filter(r => route.roles.indexOf(r) !== -1).length > 0`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo. Thanks for showing us this neat trick!

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski do know how to implemenent this solution with angular 4, I am testing but roles variable in canActivate is undefined.

Comment: @xzegga i not used angular4 yet :P

Comment: This seems the way to go in order to access routes, but how about showing or hiding components depending on the role?

Comment: Here's an example of how to use `data` to look for a specific role: https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards

Comment: My big issue with this approach is that it gives nothing in the form of suggestion to the developer as to what properties to pass with `data` for the guard. Furthermore, it's possible that multiple guards may wish to use the same property from `data` for different purposes. These two reasons make the factory method superior in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE**: applicable for **angular-rc.4 <**

@KamilKiełczewski, @NikolayRusev,

1. added in route additional data with array of routes:

```
...
{
    path: "customers",
    component: CustomersCmp,
    data: { roles: ["admin"] }
},
...
```

and in CanActivate you can get `path` from first parameter, search the same path in route config and get your described roles from data:

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    let path = route._urlSegment.pathsWithParams[0].path;
    let roles;

    if (route._routeConfig.path == path) {
        roles = route._routeConfig.data.roles
    } else {
        roles = route._routeConfig.children.find(_route => _route.path == path).data.roles;
    }

    if (...) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Of course it would be better to avoid private properties, and you can, but I cannot remember how I exactly done it.

But for my porposes I redid it in different way. The huge disadvantage of this approach, I mean for role based guard, is that every user with different roles can see all of the routes if you render them in a component automatically not manually.

2. you can extend `router-outlet`

   - http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/
   - https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492#.cxgoan9go

Comment: Would be nice to hear a comment from one of the angular2 team members. For now it seems most people are doing it this your way Andrei Shostik, which seems hacky. You need to read the roles on load and then go through your routes and check the roles according to the route. If the limitation of not having the access to the data in CanActivate is intentional we should not use it. and knowing the right way would be nice. If its not intentional, we need to know the "right" workaround. Seems like the same approach as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39097563/145334

Comment: To my previous comment, seems this issue on github is relevant: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9001

Comment: Also submited the issue for exactly this case: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11708