# Dynamic Landing page based on User Role Angular Router "~3.4.0"

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have different user roles and based on the logged in user role, I want to to change the default page(landing page) after log in. How do i achieve it, haven't found any resources online, is it something that needs to be implemented yet or I am missing something:

I have two modules ExceptionDashboard and cashierRiskprofile module routes

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { CashierRiskProfileComponent }    from "./cashierriskprofile.component";

const cashierRiskProfileRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "cashierriskprofile", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "cashierriskprofile", component: CashierRiskProfileComponent }
];

export const CashierRiskProfileRouting = RouterModule.forChild(cashierRiskProfileRoutes);
```

Above code will have default route as cashierRiskprofile.

ExceptionDashboard:

```
const exceptionDashboardRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "exceptionDashboard", component: ExceptionDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: "exceptionDetail", component: ExceptionDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: "exceptionTransaction", component: ExceptionTransactionComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

For Admin users we show CashierRiskProfile as landing page which is already defaulted, for other users I wanted to show exceptionDashboard path as landingpage. How do I change it based on UserRole.

I know how to implement CanActivateViaAuthGuard "canActivate" service to redirect to a particular page if user is not autheticated , but I am looking at changing landing page based on user roles ?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
//import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class CanActivateViaAuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(/*private authService: AuthService*/) { }

    canActivate() {
        //if logged in return true
        return true;

        //else retrun to login page
        //return false;
    }
}
```

I want to implement something which changes dynamically default page based on User Role.

Comment: Is this still relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402776/angular2-routing-canactivate-and-authguard-jwt-with-user-role-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Inside the guard rather than returning `true` or `false` you can redirect the users depending on their roles.

Example:

```
constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate() {
        //if role is system manager
        if(this.checkUserRoleFunction() == "system manager"){
           this.router.navigate(['/exceptionTransaction']);
        }else if(this.checkUserRoleFunction() == "associate"){
           this.router.navigate(['/exceptionDetail']);
        }else{
           this.router.navigate(['/exceptionTransaction']);
        }
        return false;
    }
```