# angular2 jwt with roles in CanActivate

Tags: angular

i would like know what is the best practice to make my AuthGuard with roles so i can control the admin ,superadmin and user using jwt token with roles

[here is my AuthGuard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5uGC.png)

[and here is my routers ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XOzA.png)

Comment: Please add the essential parts of your code to the question directly instead of just linking to external resources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 routing canActivate and AuthGuard (JWT) with user role parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402776/angular2-routing-canactivate-and-authguard-jwt-with-user-role-parameter)

Comment: this is my code bro its not external resources