# How to Add role based token in Angular 2, Node Js for separate Login for frontend and admin

Tags: node.js, angular

I was created a frontend and admin panel both are seperate login with separate jwt tokens and simply adding role like user or admin in localstorage from mongodb. bt here i have some problems. Still login at Frontend in browser and same browser automatically logged in Admin panel in new tab. because i have not add Role guard some people said that. Bt i dont know how to add create user and admin role and how to add role in route file. i hv path \ for Frontend login and \admin for admin login. Here is my code:

**app.route.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    loadChildren: './client/client.route.module#ClientRouteModule'
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    loadChildren: './admin/admin.route.module#AdminRouteModule'
  }
```

It is my main route file.

**client.route.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ClientComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate: [NotAuthGuard]},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [NotAuthGuard]},
      {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

It is my frontend Route file

**admin.route.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {path:'', redirectTo: '/admin/admin-login', pathMatch:'full'},
      {path:'admin-login', component:AdminLoginComponent, canActivate:[AdminNotAuthGuard]},
      {path:'admin-dashboard',component: AdminDashboardComponent, canActivate:[AdminAuthGuard] }
  }
];
```

It is my Admin Route file

**admin.auth.guard.ts**

```
    constructor(
        private authAdminService: AuthadminService,
        private router: Router
      ){ }
      canActivate(
        router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
      ){
        if(this.authAdminService.loggedIn()){
          return true;
        } else {
          this.redirectUrl = state.url;
          this.router.navigate(['admin/admin-login']);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }

**admin.notAuth.guard.ts**

 constructor(private authAdminService: AuthadminService,
              private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate(){
    if(this.authAdminService.loggedIn()){
      this.router.navigate(['admin/admin-dashboard']);
      return false;
    } else {

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  redirectUrl;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ){ }
  canActivate(
    router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ){
    if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
      return true;
    } else {
      this.redirectUrl = state.url;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Its for Frontend AuthGuard

**notAuth.guard.ts**

```
export class NotAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {
  }
  canActivate(){
    if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    } else {

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have structure that i am login in frontend that open frontend dashboard and same app same browser i am login in admin that after open admin dashboard but Still i am login in frontend and new tab i open admin then automatically open admin dashboard. Give me some solution that I am login in frontend that open user views and that i login in admin after open admin dashboard for admin views.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Roles: when your user logged in, your backend should put this user role into JWT token and send it explicite part as resposne, and your frontend should read the role and put it somewhere (in some storage)
2. To prevent application to login in different browser tabs, instead of using **local storage** use **session storage** in angular
3. You should also change code of your AuthGuard and introduce there user role checking. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402776/angular2-routing-canactivate-and-authguard-jwt-with-user-role-parameter) should help a little

Comment: 1 and 2 are completed but i don't know changes of AuthGuard. can you Give me some more descriptions?

Comment: I have a admin authguard and User authguard which i am implemented to this code?

Comment: use only one authguard which "inside" detect role https://stackoverflow.com/a/39872345/860099 (here authguard was renamed to roleguard) - read carefully whole topic in my answer previous link and you will find the answer